# Toggle switch to turn off application sounds

Tags: ios, toggle

I have multiple sounds in my application.  I want to setup a toggle switch in settings to turn these sounds off.  Here is the code that executes the sounds.

```
- (void) soundEventDidHappen:(NSString*)eventName {
//check dictionary of sounds.. if there is a corresponding sound for this event name, play it

if ([[soundIDForEventString allKeys] containsObject:eventName]) {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound ([[soundIDForEventString objectForKey:eventName] intValue]);
}
```

Comment: What is your question. You didn't ask a question, you just posted some of your requirements.

Comment: The question is what would the if / else statements be for the toggle switch?

Comment: Have you read the docs about using the settings bundle and `NSUserDefaults`? Do you know how to get the value of the toggle?

Comment: Yeah I know how to get the value of the toggle.

Comment: Then post the code (by updating your question) you have so far for getting the value. This will make it easier to offer help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a simple toggle like this:

```
bool isToggled;

- (IBAction) toggleSound{
    if(isToggled){
        isToggled = NO; //sets isToggled to false if it's already true
    }
    else{
        isToggled = YES; //sets isToggled to true if it's already false
    }
}
```

and then you could just do:

```
- (void) soundEventDidHappen:(NSString*)eventName {
    //check dictionary of sounds.. if there is a corresponding sound for this event name, play     it
    if(isToggled){

        if ([[soundIDForEventString allKeys] containsObject:eventName]) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound ([[soundIDForEventString objectForKey:eventName] intValue]);
        }
    }
}
```

Which will play the sound if `isToggled` is true. You could then use `NSUserDefaults` if you would like to save the boolean for the future:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:isToggled forKey:@"soundEnabled"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//use this to save
```

Then you could use this to get the value (most likely somewhere in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
isToggled = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"soundEnabled"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Jojodomo, thanks for this answer it helped out tremendously.  What would be the NSUserDefaults for this?