# How to toggle a sound on/off

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

i created a sound in DetailViewController,

```
 soundFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"click" withExtension:@"wav"];
s1Player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
s1Player.delegate = self;
s1Player.volume = 2;
[s1Player play];
```

i want to control the above sound in my ViewController. i created a button in ViewController, and toggle it (sound on / off).

i tried,
DetailViewController.m

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
if(viewController.stopSound) {
    [s1Player stop];
    s1Player.volume = 0;
}
else {
   [s1Player play];
    s1Player.volume = 2;
}
```

ViewController.h

```
@property BOOL stopSound;
```

in ViewController.m

```
- (void) setSoundAction {

if(_stopSound){
    _stopSound = NO;
}
else{
    _stopSound = YES;
}
}
```

If the above code is not understandable or not cleared please suggest me how to toggle a button i.e, sound on and sound off on DetailViewController.  Because Sound placed on DetailViewController.

Comment: You can use s1Player.volume = 0; to Stop Sound.

Comment: i written the above code is right or wrong…

Comment: its wrong. You created new instance of class and trying to control your player which is playing in some other instance.

Comment: could you show some code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961139/toggle-switch-to-turn-off-application-sounds Check it..

Comment: i tried but not working… i edit my code ,please check is it correct?

Comment: my toggle is not changing

Answer (score 0):

What you want is just toggle button, then how about this?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *toggleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    toggleButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    [toggleButton setTitle:@"Toggle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [toggleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSound:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  //execute the method when touched
    [self.view addSubview:toggleButton];
}

- (void)toggleSound:(UIButton *)btn
{
    static BOOL muted;  //remember the current status of AVAudioPlayer object.
    muted = !muted;     //toggle!!

    if(muted) {
        s1player.volume = 0.0;
    } else {
        s2player.volume = 1.0;  //max value for volume is 1.0
    }
}
```